# How to restrict access to different pages in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have controller **Users**:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ......
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)
  end
  ......    
end
```

Now users profiles are at **/users/1**, **/users/2**, etc. and list of users is at **/users/**.

I want to give special access:

- user can see only own profile
- admin can see the list of users and any profile

How can I restrict access this way?

Comment: There are many, many ways this could be done. There are libraries that do it, you could spin a drop-dead simple approach (hint: all you need to do is check the role of the current user and show the appropriate page). There are many tutorials that cover both rolling your own and using libraries. As worded now the question is quite broad.

Comment: you can use cancan or rolify and combine it with devise's `current_user` method. If the user is admin then allow him otherwise check whether the id of the profile he is visiting is equal to `current_user.id` else throw him to default page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `current_user` defined and your `User` class has an `admin` attribute you can do the following:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ......
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if current_user.admin || @user == current_user
      # render the show screen
    else
      # redirect to wherever
    end
  end

  def index
    if current_user.admin
      @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)
      # render the index screen
    else
      # redirect to wherever
    end

  end
  ......    
end
```

Or you could just use one of the plenty of authorization gems out there, like cancancan or pundit.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ACL libraries like [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) or [pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) or from [ruby-toolbox.com](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably handle this by having two different endpoints, something like `/profile` and `/admin/users/1`. Then you have different controllers for them:

```
UserProfileController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```

and:

```
class Admin::UsersController < AdminController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    render 'user_profile/show' # or another template if you like
  end
end

class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_action :ensure_admin

  def ensure_admin
    if !current_user.admin?
      raise ActionController::RoutingError, 'Not Found'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your url `user/1/` you grab the param id and compare it to the current user ID in a hook :

```
before_action :auth_user

private

def auth_user
  unless params[:id].to_s == current_user.id.to_s
redirect_to root_path
end
```

Regarding the admin you probably have a dedicated namespace, with even more thorough checks,  where you can see user profiles.